# bind not a value, but a function (with getting value of this function)

Tags: c++, binding, functor

Let's say I have following function:

```
int foo (int a)
{
  return something;
}
```

How can I do something like this?

```
vector<int> v;

std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind1st(std::minus<int>(), foo) );
```

I want this to work like: `for_each` passes current element into the functor, functor calls `foo` and then subtracts the passed vector element and result of calling `foo`. Is it possible to make this using only std, not boost or self-written functors?

Comment: 1) Where do you want to store the result of substraction? Modify the vector or create another one?

2) `foo` function is implemented to return the parameter value, so what is the point to substract the value from itself (always returns zero)?

Comment: 1) Let say i don't want to modify original vector 2) What if i have another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is slightly horrible but in C++11...

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

int foo(int a) 
{
    return a;
}

int operator-(int b, std::function<int(int)> a)
{
    return b - a(b);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind((int(*)(int, std::function<int(int)>))(&operator-), std::placeholders::_1, &foo) );
    return 0;
}
```

less horrible way using lambdas

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int a) -> int { return a - foo(a); });
```

Comment: If you're going to use C++11, then just write a lambda.

Comment: Well yeah, he seemed more interested in the binding part... I'll edit in a lambda example

Comment: Hm, do you really think that the first variant of code (without lambdas) is maintainable? =)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to modify the vector, so I would assume you want to transform it to another one.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int foo(int a)
{
    return a;
}

int foo2(int a)
{
    return a - foo(a);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    v.push_back(10);
    v.push_back(20);
    v.push_back(30);

    std::vector<int> v2;
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(v2), foo2);

    return 0;
}
```